# WindowLoaded event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added WindowLoaded event as a routed event handler in constructor but not sure if this is a right way of declaring/suing loading of a window.

```
    this.AddHandler(Window.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(WindowLoaded));
```

Currently seems working since as soon as I run the App I get a empty window with borders only without its contents.

Question is that how can I use WindowLoaded() event in WPF? I was expecting to select it from top dropdown box in VS2010 but I guess have to enter it manually. Is that right?

Cheers,
Amit

Comment: There is no event named "WindowLoaded" or "LoadedEvent".  There's only Loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow Mark's advice, or alternatively, you can add the loaded event in your `MainWindow.xaml` (Visual Studio will generate the handler for you if you press ctrl+space in the Loaded attribute):

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
    <!-- your code -->
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the Loaded event in either the GUI:

[image]

Or in the codebehind of the control:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

void MainWindow_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{

}
```

Comment: it is funny that my properties window doesn't show what your image has! it only shows Properties tab and there are only few properties.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 for me the proprieties window has an icon of a wrench and one of a lightning bolt next to the Name field (without the words 'Properties' or 'Events' shown above). Took me a second to notice; in case that helps anyone.